# Kill and resume a rsnapshot backup properly

Tags: rsnapshot

Suppose that after starting a `rsnapshot` backup on my laptop I notice that it will take too long time and that I have to shutdown the laptop in a few minutes.

Is there a way to quit `rsnapshot` without messing up the running backup and resume it later (for example after rebooting the laptop) without problems?

Comment: I guess this is a complete answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6663/what-happens-if-rsnapshot-rdiff-backup-gets-interrupted-in-the-middle-of-a-tra . But to make it short, the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the output of `rsnapshot` available, you can safely repeat the `rsync` command that it used. You do not (and should not) delete `hourly.0` if you're going to do this.

For example, on one of my systems this is (almost) what gets run by `rsnapshot`, so this could be copied and pasted and rerun:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -avzS --delete --delete-excluded --numeric-ids --fake-super \
    --exclude-from=/usr/local/etc/rsnapshot/EXCLUDE-qnap.inc \
    --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh \
    --link-dest=/backup/Rsync/NewZealand/QNAP/Data/hourly.1/share/ \
    admin@10.11.12.13:/share/ \
    /backup/Rsync/NewZealand/QNAP/Data/hourly.0/share/
```